# Discussion Board: allow anonymous users to view post content, not just post list

Tags: discussion-board

I'm working on an area of my SP 2010 Server site (based on publishing template) that is open to anonymous users and includes a discussion board.

I have a page that includes a web part to show the discussion board list of posts (or topics), which works when the user is anonymous. However, when they click a link to view the content of a post, they are prompted to log in.

Ideally we want the post list and the post content views to be available to anonymous users, but replying to and creating posts requires the user to log in, and be a member of a specific group.

i.e. this URL would be viewable to all users - anonymous or logged in: .../community/Developer/Lists/Forums/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fcommunity%2FDeveloper%2FLists%2FForums%2FTesting%20Permissions%20for%20true%20public%20space&FolderCTID=0x01200200783F7E4A16B68A47A9251FBDA8BB2D99

For the List permissions I have

```
Name: Anonymous Users
Type: Anonymous Users
Permission Levels: View Items

Name: Developer Members
Type: SharePoint Group
Permission Levels: Contribute, Read
```

Is it possible to do as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this reply in the technet forums:

As you are working with publishing portal, you have to turn OFF Lockdown Mode in SharePoint 2010.
Read more about Lockdown feature here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/22/lockdown-mode-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

For publishing sites, the Lockdown mode is enabled by default. Be aware that turning this OFF leaves you security risks. But you can also have seperate site for discussion board  just to minimize the risks.

Eg:

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity "ViewFormPagesLockDown" -URL http://mysite
```